# Java: Making a editable list of items in a JPanel/JFrame

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, input

Sorry, I'm kind of a beginner to GUI interfaces (well, a beginner to java, really), and I was wondering: How does one make a list of items that the user can add items to or remove items from, with the press of a + or - button?

What I really want (sorry if I'm being a little vague here) is one of those lists you sometimes see in application windows, which looks like a text box but cannot be typed in. Right now my application (it's a small app to organize the schedule of a hospital) just reads from a text file and writes to another text file. No GUI, no window, the user just writes a bunch of names in the text file, one per line, then runs the jar and opens the output file and the schedule is there. I want them to just be able to add or remove names from a list with buttons — adding a name by clicking 'plus' and typing the name, and removing a name by selecting the name and clicking 'minus'. I still, however, want it to save to a text file, so that the next time the user opens the app, all the names are still on the list.
Just to be clear, I don't want a list displaying the output (i.e. the names organized into a schedule), just one containing the input.

Thanks a lot for any help you can give.

Comment: This should have all the info you need: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html

Comment: did u try something? may be u can start seeing JComboBox, JTable or JList

Answer (score 5):

You probably want a `JList` with a couple of `JButton` instances to add/remove items.

[image: JList with buttons]

See:

- [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html)
- [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)